# Can you create a cascading dropdown in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, cascadingdropdown

I'm trying to make a cascading dropdown in my project where the user will first select a car brand with one dropdown, then car model from that brand, then the version and then the model year. I've been searching for it for a long time but I keep finding stuff about React JS and not react native. The documentation of [react-native-dropdown-picker](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/) doesn't tell anything about something like that as well.
If anyone can help me out here, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you have a reference to a ReactJS version that does the same thing as you want (so that your goal is clear to readers)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dependent-dropdown-ibbwd?file=/src/pages/Main/index.js
Basically its something like this but on react native.